# This extension requires the Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server to communicate with SQL Server

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

I'm trying to connect mssql database with php 7 and ubuntu 16.04. I installed odbc driver and check it with sample_c_linux file its working but when I'm executing my code its giving this error.

> [PDOException]   SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: This extension requires the
>   Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server to communicate with SQL
>   Server. Access the following URL to download the ODBC Driver 13 for
>   SQL Server for x86: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712

```
$db = DB::connection('sqlsrv');
$sql = "sp_EntityFullList";
$procedure = $db->getPdo()->exec( $sql );
```

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50420

Comment: @GabrielHeming I already install from this link with looking instructions. But it doesn't worked.

Comment: It's so weird. `sqlsrv` is a bit new to Linux, but still weird. May you change from `sqlsrv` to `FreeTDS` or it's not an option?

Comment: @GabrielHeming actually sqlsrv its name of environment which I gave in .env file. also I can connect tsql -S serveradress -U sa

Answer (score -1):

Still you need to install ODBC 11 driver.

Ref: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36434